# Flutter http post, response body is always empty

Tags: flutter, dart, post, cors

I'm struggling with http post in order to get some data from an API, but the response.body is always empty. Testing on https://reqbin.com/ works fine, so the problem is inside the code.

```
try {

        final response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(
              'https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/PlatitorTvaRest/api/v8/ws/tva'),
          headers: <String, String>{
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":
                "*", // Required for CORS support to work
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":
                'true', // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
                "Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,HEAD,DELETE",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: jsonEncode({
            'cui': _identificationController.text.trim(),
            'data': DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now())
          }),
        );

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          // If the server responds successfully
          // then parse the JSON.

          print(response.body.length);
          if(response.body.isNotEmpty)
            {
              final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
                print(responseData);
            }
          else
            {
              print("Response body is empty\n");
            
            }

        } else {
          // If the server did not return a 200 CREATED response,
          // then throw an exception.


          throw Exception(
              'Failed to fetch company data from ANAF: ${response.statusCode}');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
```

While executing I've got two scenarios:

1. response code 200, response.body empty
2. response code 500 - internal error

Also I had to disable web security in chrome.dart file in order to be able to execute the `http.post`. Any idea how can I configure the CORS?

Comment: could you also paste the response.body output?

Comment: Are the parameters you are sending in the body correct and as per the requirement???

Comment: @AshutoshPatole response.body output in my case is empty cause length is 0, and it should have looked like this: {
    "cod": 200,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "found": [],
    "notFound": [1234]
}

Comment: @Anand yes, here is the API info: https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/PlatitorTvaRest/api/v8/

Comment: 1. Adding CORS headers to the *request* will have zero effect. They need to be added by the server. 2. The linked spec you provided shows that the request body should be a JSON array of JSON objects. You are just including one JSON object.

Comment: @RichardHeap works with only one JSON object. Tested on reqbin.com and respons fine. Also here is the post body from the API info which includes only one object: Post Body:
   [
    {
        "cui": _Numar_, "data":"_Data interogarii_"     
    },
    {
        "cui": _Numar_, "data":"_Data interogarii_"     
    }  
   ]

Comment: That body is definitely a JSON array - with 2 JSON objects. Note the outermost `[]` Can you update the question showing a working request using any tool?

Comment: @RichardHeap yes, that was the root cause. Many thanks. Any idea how to fix the CORS?

Comment: CORS is only relevant because of Flutter Web, correct? So, you run into the CORS because your flutter app is being served by one web server and it is trying to access a second web server. Unless that 2nd web server helps (by adding the CORS headers) you will get an error. If you cannot get the 2nd server to change, you need to add an endpoint on the first web server (which you can access without CORS). Your app will access that endpoint, which will connect to webservicesp.anaf.ro and relay the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of the POST must be a JSON array, even if there is one JSON object.

The following code (with the outermost `[]`s) works. If you remove the `[]` it fails.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/PlatitorTvaRest/api/v8/ws/tva'),
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
    body: json.encode(
      [
        {'cui': 1234, 'data': '2015-02-14'}
      ],
    ),
  );

  print(response.body);
}
```